# What controls should my help desk team have over our user's accounts?

Tags: crud, user-control

We are building a software, which we have companies registering their products.
We (**the administrator**) will have the help desk team that'll be able to help our users (**companies**) in case of problems.

Our platform performs transactions, and with such, we expect **user support**.

What controls should my help desk team have over our user's account?

For example, **may they...**

- Change account basic information? (Address, phone numbers, names, e-mails)
- Change account password? Or send new password email?
- Change transaction info?
- Cancel a transaction?
- Refund a transaction?
- Add or delete users? (users inside their area can delete their account, and can create new account in log in page)

As you've seen, I'm new to this area and I'm not sure what are the market standards for these settings.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of these should be directly under anyone's control

What I mean is, no-one should be able to simply delete an account/transaction change a password etc. Each of these processes needs to be created in such a way that when executed all the relevant audit trails and checks are made.

Once you have done that, you are no longer trusting an individual, whomever initiates the action becomes less important because whatever happens the process is guaranteed to be followed.

Program your system so that no "admin" account is ever needed.

Comment: "What do you mean with an "admin" account? Do you mean something similar to the root user on Linux systems, or a user belonging to an "admin" group that has slightly more privileges but still needs to pass through all access controls and audit trails?

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed I was a bit scared of opening everything to help desk employees or managers (admin access). I will follow your instructions accordingly.

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau I understood admin access as a user group with slightly more privileges. If not, please clarify Ewan.

Comment: @RA828 Ewan seems to be saying that *everything they do can be audited*, so they can get in trouble for doing the wrong things and those things can be undone. That might be more important than technical controls preventing them from doing things. (Is that right?)

Comment: you might have a business criteria for a process such as "only team leaders can complete step 6 of process Z" in which case there is an "admin" group of sorts for those people. I meant more a general "admin = i can break the rules when required" role. Although you should try to avoid both